# Getting an "Illegal Initial Capacity Error"

Tags: java, android

Getting this error after graphView() is created. I think it has something to do with graphView(). The weird thing is that everything was working fine a while ago then I added two new activities that are working fine.

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.weightogo, PID: 10342
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal initial capacity: -4
                      at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:448)
                      at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:467)
                      at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(LinkedHashMap.java:383)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.adjustHorizontal(GridLabelRenderer.java:947)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.adjustSteps(GridLabelRenderer.java:980)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.draw(GridLabelRenderer.java:1113)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.drawGraphElements(GraphView.java:307)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer.draw(GridLabelRenderer.java:1108)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.drawGraphElements(GraphView.java:307)
                      at com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.onDraw(GraphView.java:336)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1963)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is the function that uses the graphView:

```
public void buildGraph() {
        MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Double> HiProfWang = userWeightTables.fetchWeight(db);
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.sexbot);
        DataPoint[] dpvals = new DataPoint[HiProfWang.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < HiProfWang.size(); i++) {
            dpvals[i] = new DataPoint(i + 1, HiProfWang.get(i));
        }
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dpvals);

        graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(false);

        if(HiProfWang.size() < 7){
            graph.getViewport().setMinX(1);
        }
        else{
            graph.getViewport().setMinX(HiProfWang.size() - 6);
        }
        graph.getViewport().setMaxX(HiProfWang.size());
        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        // enable scrolling
        graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true); // horizontal scrolling
        graph.addSeries(series);
        displayWeightDifference(HiProfWang);
    }
```

I have been debugging for a while now but I dont see any error other than the app closing right after the OnCreate() for the activity with the graph view.

This is the Oncreate function for this activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        weightButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weightButton);
        displayDifference = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayDifference);
        displayAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayAverage);
        displayWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayWeight);
        ccButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ccButton);
        initWeight();
        initCalorieCounter();
        displayUserWeight();
        displayWeightAverage();
        buildGraph();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using the graphview library. For me it happened when `.setMaxX` was less than `.setMinX` It happens because your graph axis range can not be a negative value. You need to make sure your code for setting your axis does not allow `.setMinX` to be greater than `.setMaxX`. Where you have

```
if(HiProfWang.size() < 7){
graph.getViewport().setMinX(1);
        }
```

It is possible for `setMaxX` to be less than `.setMinX(1)` if `HiProfWang.size()` returns 0.

I'm not sure what the behavior would be if minX and maxX were equal.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21718334)

Comment: What do I need to clarify about check `.setMinX` is less than `.setMaxX` ?

Comment: Unless you are entirely sure, this solves the problem, you should have posted your experience as a comment, not as an answer.